# Convert UIImage coordinates to CIImage coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ciimage

I have an ARKit app that scans a QR code and sends me the coordinates of the corners. I'm able to draw a box around the QR code with these coordinates with UIKit. However, I'm trying to use a CIImage filter, which has a different coordinate system with 0,0 at bottom left instead of top left. To convert from UIImage coordinates to CIImage coordinates, I flipped the y-axis, but I also had to multiply x,y by 2. This seemed to convert properly but i don't get why 2x worked. Anyone know to convert a CGPoint from UIImage/UIkit to CiImage? Thanks!

Comment: 2x is the screen scale. Better to use the screen scale when converting your coordinates.

Comment: That sounds like scale, as Leo says (UIImage works in points, which are 1/72nd of an inch, regardless of resolution (non-retina, 2x retina, or 3x retina) CIImage, if memory serves, works in pixels.